# Community edition UML tool

Tags: uml, tool-uml

Can anyone suggest me a free or community edition UML tool for C++. Any UML tool is fine but I need something that can generate class templates for c++. Why I need to generate class codes is because, if in future if I make some changes to my Class diagram it should easily reflect in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [JUDE community](http://jude.change-vision.com/jude-web/product/community.html) - now known as Astah.

Comment: Alright, No thanks. Can get you a beer :-).. To upvote you can see how my reputation is but have accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux or OSX then [Umbrello](http://uml.sourceforge.net/) is very well featured and includes code generation.